# Bleachbit Icons Missing in usr/share/applications on Lubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: lubuntu, icons, bleachbit

Morning:

Recently did a clean install of Lubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and found that the icons for Bleachbit 2.0 (that came with the Bionic install) did not appear under System Tools.

When I went into usr/share/applications I found they are not there either.

I tried to import the icons from an Lubuntu 16.04 install (from usr/share/applications) but when I brought those two icons over on a USB stick (Bleachbit & Bleachbit as Root) they were broken when the file manager displayed the contents of the USB stick.

I then tried to install Bleachbit 4.2 from a deb file but it also does not install the icons into usr/share/applications.

I uninstalled Bleachbit 4.2 and reinstalled Bleachbit 2.0 but it still does not show the icons.

Is this a problem with the theming that Lubuntu 18.04.6 uses?

Does anyone know how to correct this so that I can have the Bleachbit icons back?

It's totally cosmetic but driving me nuts.

Help?

Comment: Please add output of `which bleachbit`, `apt-cache policy bleachbit` . Are we talking about official deb-package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/bleachbit ?

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Answer (score 3):

**It seems that your are trying to break normally working system.

Do not copy files into the directories which are controlled by APT system!**

If you want to (re)install BleachBit - use its official deb-packages [from repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/bleachbit) with commands shown below

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bleachbit
```

and you will get its icons [in place](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/bleachbit/filelist):

- `/usr/share/applications/bleachbit-root.desktop`
- `/usr/share/applications/bleachbit.desktop`

I see these icons on for example:

- Lubuntu session:

  [image: Lubuntu]

  You can change this icons from ugly variant to pretty  by doing right mouse click on the menu item, visiting *Properties* and selecting `/usr/share/pixmaps/bleachbit.png` as image file to get

  [image: normal Bleachbit on Lubuntu]
- LXDE
  [image: LXDE]
- MATE DE

  [image: MATE]

---

If you want to get newer BleachBit 4.2 - you can use some thirdparty PPA like [this](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/apps), so install using commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

Reverting to 2.0 is possible by `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` followed by `sudo ppa-purge ppa:kelebek333/apps` .

Comment: Thanks, the png's in the pixmap folder were exactly what I was after. You de man. B